# Explanation of matrix transformations

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I've been looking for something that can help me understand matrix transformations.  I've been to [multiple](http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/XNA-Game-Development-%28First-Steps%29.aspx) [different](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2D/Coll_Detection_Overview.php) [sites](http://www.austincc.edu/cchrist1/GAME1343/TransformedCollision/TransformedCollision.htm), including [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29) and quite a lot of related questions on SE and other forums.  I also posted a similar question in another forum and was unable to get results. Oh, and I visited a number of learning sites like Khan Academy to no avail.

The linked websites all provide methods to calculate transformed pixel-perfect collisions, but they require matrices for input.  Some of the sites tell you to ignore how matrices work and focus on the collision methods, but how can you do that if you need to use matrices for input?

In trying to figure out how to convert my data into matrices and use XNA's mysterious matrix transformation tools, I ran into one of math's famous jargon-barriers with such head-scratchers as *vector space* and *linearity*, among plenty others.

So the question is, **can you explain how to create position, rotation, and scaling matrices, as well as how to combine them and *why* they work?**

As I've explained, I wouldn't be asking this question if I hadn't exhausted all of my searching queries.  I am no more advanced in my mathematical understanding than Pre-Calculus.

Comment: Links which I give you aren't directly connected to XNA but you have here almost everything what you should know:
[OpenGL](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/)
[DirectX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206269%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also struggled a bit on matrices. As I can remember, the videos from BSVino helped me a lot. https://www.youtube.com/user/BSVino/videos
This guy provides several videos about maths for game developers and there are a few on matrices as well (rotation, scale, perspective transform etc..)